# Disable www redirect WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to disable redirection from *www.site.com* to *site.com* and vice-versa, I used `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` but it didn't work. my *htaccess* is clean.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to redirect my website to non www, just trying to avoid those redirections to www. or no www.

Comment: if you set the both www and non-www it will chance to duplicate content in google search result.

Answer (score 1):

There is hardcore way to stop this, but I personally don't like it, because next time you update your Wordpress, this change will be fixed.

You can edit the file: ./wp-includes/canonical.php on line 587 and just remove or comment the whole section:

```
/**
 * Filters the canonical redirect URL.
 *
 * Returning false to this filter will cancel the redirect.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @param string $redirect_url  The redirect URL.
 * @param string $requested_url The requested URL.
 */
$redirect_url = apply_filters( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );

// // yes, again -- in case the filter aborted the request
if ( ! $redirect_url || strip_fragment_from_url( $redirect_url ) == strip_fragment_from_url( $requested_url ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( $do_redirect ) {
    // protect against chained redirects
    if ( ! redirect_canonical( $redirect_url, false ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url, 301 );
        exit();
    } else {
        // Debug
        // die("1: $redirect_url<br />2: " . redirect_canonical( $redirect_url, false ) );
        return;
    }
} else {
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

[image]

Just Add Your Site address AND WordPress address like

```html
http://example.com
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to redirect my website to non www, just trying to avoid those redirections to www. or no www.